# Could anyone help me get my app back on eBay x

Tags: itunes

I am having trouble getting my eBay app back since I downloaded new s settings from you what come through every now and again , only My old eBay just keep s crashing now so when I tried to get a new eBay app to work it tell s me to put password for Apple ID something iTunes  but my daughter set this up and used her email address but this is no longer being used and we can not remember the password so I can t get it to work cause you can t send me nothing cause the email no longer s exist so I don t no what to do as I have tried but still keep s saying that old email address could you please help me as I can t get on eBay no more

Comment: Let's close this until we get a clearer picture of what app you want installed onto which device. Would you look over [about] and [ask] and make an edit to list. What one device needs to load the app. I'll add a brief answer on how to check your AppleID in case it's that simple.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the password for your Apple ID to download the new app.
First work through that at:

https://appleid.apple.com

From there you can edit your question if you still need help using an ID to download the ebay app.